# Dynamically add rows to Google Charts using JQuery loop

Tags: c#, jquery, json, google-visualization

I want to loop through a JSON return from C# to dynamically add rows to a google chart. I have used this same code, time and again, and it will not load into the chart.

I can see the Json coming back to the browser and have tested it with RestClient so I am happy the C# bit works, but I am not seeing why the Json won't load into the Google line chart and create the line. There is an error showing on the chart `Cannot read property 'getTime' of null`. I have tried a few different ways of creating the array for data.AddRow.

JQuery Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetJsonChartData", "ProjectCharts")',
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    async: false,
    data: { serial: serial, uid: uid, from: from, to: to },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (d) {
        $.each(d, function (index, item) {                        
            data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), Number(item.ReadingValue), item.ToolTip]);                   
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error loading chart data.")
    } 
});
```

and my Json looks like:

```
   [{
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:43:39",
    "ReadingValue": "17.5",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:43\r\n Value: 17.5"
  },
  {
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:45:39",
    "ReadingValue": "16.8",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:45\r\n Value: 16.8"
  },
  {
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:47:39",
    "ReadingValue": "16.1",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:47\r\n Value: 16.1"
  },
  {
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:49:39",
    "ReadingValue": "15.7",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:49\r\n Value: 15.7"
  }]
```

I create the Json as follow:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonChartData(string serial, string uid, string from, string to) {           
    var g = new GetChartData(_configuration);
    var items = g.GetChartDataFromSqlServer(serial, uid, f, t);
    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.Indented));
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea why this works in another application and won't work in this one. I noticed that the for each loop was not being hit and I was getting an error in the console about the Json data as show above. It saw the Json return string from C# as one long object.

I added the parseJSON into the JQuery and it worked.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'ProjectCharts/GetJsonChartData',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            async: false,
            data: { serial: serial, uid: uid, from: from, to: to },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (d) {
                var parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);
                console.log("data: " + parsedData);               
                $.each(parsedData, function (index, item) {                    
                    data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), Number(item.ReadingValue)]);
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading chart");
            }
```

If anyone can explain to me why this would not work initially, I would really like to know.

Answer (score 3):

the chart seems to draw fine, using the same data, just hard-coded here...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn({type: 'date', label: 'Date'});
  data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Value'});
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});

  var d = [{
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:43:39",
    "ReadingValue": "17.5",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:43\r\n Value: 17.5"
  },
  {
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:45:39",
    "ReadingValue": "16.8",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:45\r\n Value: 16.8"
  },
  {
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:47:39",
    "ReadingValue": "16.1",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:47\r\n Value: 16.1"
  },
  {
    "ReadingDate": "2018-12-04 09:49:39",
    "ReadingValue": "15.7",
    "ToolTip": "Tue, 04 Dec 18 09:49\r\n Value: 15.7"
  }];

  $.each(d, function (index, item) {
    data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), Number(item.ReadingValue), item.ToolTip]);
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: will you please share the rest of the javascript code, or whatever else may be different?

Comment: I have created a fiddle here, I have hardcoded some values to make it easier to test. https://jsfiddle.net/hmz9ro45/1/

Comment: I am also getting an error in the console - 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [' then the rest of the json follows...

Comment: I am convinced the chart is loading before the data comes back.

Comment: try putting all of the chart code inside the success callback

Comment: I tried that and didn't work. However, the error I see in the console seems to relate to var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length,
  type = toType( obj ); in Jquery. It just isn't parsing the data. I put the data for the chart in the console and the objects are null. Im stumped.